# ggplot2: make the points on the line a darker color than the line color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make each point on the graph a different color from the line. Here is sample data.

```
df <- structure(list(yrmonth = structure(c(17167, 17167, 17167, 17198, 
17198, 17198, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17257, 17257, 17257), class = "Date"), 
    index = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L), .Label = c("E-W", "N-S", "OS"), class = "factor"), 
    N = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), data = c(129, 
    141, 27, 150.5, 209, 87, 247.5, 243, 188, 223, 226.5, 170
    )), .Names = c("yrmonth", "index", "N", "data"), row.names = 31:42, class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code for the plot.

```
df$yrmonth <- lubridate::ymd(df$yrmonth)

ggplot(df, aes(x=yrmonth,y=data,colour=factor(index), group=index)) + 
  geom_line(size=.4) + 
  geom_point(size=1)
```

I would like the green dots to be a darker green, the orange dots to be a darker orange and so forth.

Comment: A quick fix is to use `geom_line(size=.4, alpha=0.5)`, which makes the lines more transparent and therefore it looks like the dots are darker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a filled point marker (shapes 21 through 25), which would allow you to set the fill colors for the points separately from the colors of the lines. In the code below, I use the same hues (the `h` argument to the `hcl` function) for the points and lines, but a lower luminance (the `l` argument to `hcl`) for the points so that they will be darker than the lines. I've also increased the line and point sizes to make it easier to see the difference.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=yrmonth,y=data)) + 
  geom_line(size=1, aes(colour=factor(index))) + 
  geom_point(size=3, aes(fill=factor(index)), shape=21, colour="#FFFFFF00") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length=4)[1:3], 100, 70)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length=4)[1:3], 100, 40)) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(colour="Index", fill="Index")
```

[image]

Comment: Is this right?  When I run it on my machine, the points have black circles around them

Comment: Filled point markers have both a border and a fill. `stroke=0` is supposed to get rid of the border. If you change `stroke=0` to `colour="#FFFFFF00"`, does that get rid of the black circles around the points?

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. "#FFFFFF" is the color "white". The `00` added to the end makes it completely transparent, effectively getting rid of the point border. `stroke=0` should mean a point border of zero width (which is what I get on my Mac), but maybe it doesn't work that way on some systems.